Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<byte, byte, bool[*,*]>'
I get an error:
Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action<byte, byte, bool[*,*]>'
This is my minimal example code which I feel should compile but causes the above mentioned error:
using System;
                    
public class Program {
  void EraseGoodBlocks(bool OverridePreviousTests, ref bool[,] DeviceResults) {
    ForAllDevicesResults(eraser, ref DeviceResults);
    void eraser(byte BoardNo, byte DeviceNo, ref bool[,] device_results) {}
  }
    
  void ForAllDevicesResults(Action<byte, byte, bool[,]> action, ref bool[,] result){
    for (byte Board = 0; Board < 4; Board++){
      for (byte Device = 0; Device < 16; Device++){
        action(Board, Device, result);
      }
    }
  }
}


The code uses delegates and references which complicates matters. Where did I go wrong.

remove ref from eraser's last parameter

... as arrays are passed already as references

@Selvin arrays are not passed by reference unless you use ref/out, just like literally every other parameter.  That they are a reference is not the same thing.

They are passed as reference...but it is a copy. I didn't use word "by"

Also code has C smell .... In C array are passed as copy so you cannot modify its elements. That's why I wrote this. As long as OP just wana modify elements ref is not necessary (also from the code context it's seem to be unnecessary as it is called in loop)

@selvin It is Pascal code that was ported to C and then ported to C#. It has alot of smells, none of it good.

The message is not very clear, but the issue is that you are passing eraser where an Action<byte, byte, bool[,]> is expected. And the third parameter of eraser is a ref bool[,], not a bool[,] as expected.
As proposed by Selvin, you may change the signature of eraser and remove the ref on the third parameter.
If you really need to pass the third parameter of the delegate as a ref bool[,], you will not be able to declare the delegate as an action.
Instead you must declare your own delegate:
delegate void BlockAction(byte BoardNo, byte DeviceNo, ref bool[,] device_results);

And add the ref modifier when calling it:
delegate void BlockAction(byte BoardNo, byte DeviceNo, ref bool[,] device_results);

void EraseGoodBlocks(bool OverridePreviousTests, ref bool[,] DeviceResults)
{
    ForAllDevicesResults(eraser, ref DeviceResults);

    void eraser(byte BoardNo, byte DeviceNo, ref bool[,] device_results)
    {

    }
}

void ForAllDevicesResults(BlockAction action, ref bool[,] result)
{
    for (byte Board = 0; Board < 4; Board++)
    {
        for (byte Device = 0; Device < 16; Device++)
        {
            action(Board, Device, ref result);  // add ref here
        }
    }
}


You can not pass by reference using Action. so Action<byte, byte, bool[,]> does not match with void eraser(byte BoardNo, byte DeviceNo, ref bool[,] device_results) device_results is expected to be passed via reference. and "Action<byte, byte, ref bool[,]>" is illegal. If you absolutely need to pass by reference you can make your own delegate :
delegate void MyDelegate(byte BoardNo, byte DeviceNo, ref bool[,] device_results);

